# Regarding ibm.data.db2 nuget package

Tags: asp.net, db2, nuget, websphere, nuget-package

I am trying to download ibm.data.db2 in Visual studio 2019 nuget packet. But for some reason only ibm.data.db2.core is available but a year back ibm.data.db2 was available. Is there a way I can download the older version or core works?

Answer (score 1):

It has been removed from Nuget for unknown reason. I am also trying to find one. I had to copy the DLL and add a reference to it to run an old project.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I was able to find an [archive](https://archive.org/details/ibm.data.db2.core.7z) and yet another [one](http://depositfiles.com/files/6s0dke560).
The removal probably has to do with it being out of support. Did you need support for it? I did not too.